# Using PDFCreator's Command Line Arguments in PHP exec()

Tags: php, command-line

I have tried to use the Zend Framework to do my PDF conversion in PHP but cannot figure out how to install it. I found this program that allows for PDFs to be printed/converted via the command line, so I thought I could do an exec() command in PHP to run the program and convert my file on the server for me.

The program is PDFCreator from pdfforge.org and I am trying to convert .DOC files to .PDF files. This command line below works perfectly when running from cmd.exe. However, when running it from PHP I believe that it is trying to execute under the user System and not working properly. (I did a php exec('whoami') and it came back as System.) I also changed the user of which Apache opens up as to an Admin account and still have been unable to get it to work.

`"C:\Program Files\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe" /OptionsFile"C:\PDFCreator.ini" /PF"C:\test.doc"`

Any thoughts as to why it I cannot get the same behavior when running the command using exec()?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because Apache user and account user should be the same, ex: your windows user is Pedro, so Apache user should be Pedro...you shoul open the services.msc and in the session tab allow apache to interact with the current desktop....in that way, the share the same windows session and desktop....but it shoud represent a security risk and it's not recommended.

Saludos.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did all of that and now my problem is even more weird. It executes the command and sends it to the printer (the PDF convertor) adds it to the queue and says it is printed. The thing is there is no output and the size of the print job is too small to be a document. 

Does this mean that there is a file access issue that I don't know how to fix?

Comment: Yes...i assume you have admin rights, so, i will try to access the files on server side...ex: en your www put a directory named docs...an try access on that folder instead of C:\